# Print largest integer you can with the fewest characters

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, number

Find a way to output a large integer with few characters. Solutions will be scored based on the magnitude of the number and shortness of code.

EDIT: Let's impose a time limit of a minute on sensible hardware, where sensible is a PC you can buy off the shelves.

Comment: So much for Ackerman(9,9) :P

Comment: Note that the results highly depend on the output device (/dev/stdout - slowest since it involves graphics, /dev/null - fastest cause it doesn't do anything, | wc -l - medium).

Comment: here is a proposed evaluation formula `magnitude / (characters^2 * time)`

Comment: @Shinkirou I would measure my time in decades, so I will get a very huge score :P

Comment: print '10' - since you haven't specified the base, this is using base-Graham's Number

Comment: As per @Skizz smartass comment, I assume the integer has to consist solely of the digits 0-9 in base 10, so things like the literal strings "9e+999" or "9^9^9" or "Ackerman(9,9)" are out, even though they technically represent integers?

Comment: The question should either restrict the size of the code `what is the highest number with 100 bytes of code`, or enforce a minimum number `generate a number, at least 9^1000) as pure digits with as few code as you can`. Searching for minimum and maximum the same time would need a conversion function, how to judge on smaller numbers generated with less code, since you cannot ensure that the shortest code will generate the largest number automatically.

Comment: It depends on what shelves you have.

Comment: Voted to close as not constructive. One year, and still no winning criteria.

Answer (score 31):

## JavaScript (10)

```
alert(1/0)
```

Prints "Infinity", did I win? :)

Comment: Wouldn't `alert(Infinity);` work too?

Comment: But, this is codegolf :P

Comment: what about `alert('∞')` ?

Comment: That would be too obvious :) (And that symbol encoded in UTF-8 would need 3 bytes, resulting in the same length)

Comment: Prove infinity is an integer :-)

Comment: @M28: I thought code golf was about character count, not byte count. `∞` is only one character even if it requires 3 bytes to represent in UTF-8.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party... but `alert(1/0)` works as well and is 10 characters.

Comment: That's great, a little late, but I edited my answer, thanks!

Comment: @Paul: Chuck Norris counted to infinity, twice. I asked him if it was an integral number and he said: "I don't count fractions, just fractures" I think that proves it.

Comment: @Paul typeof(1/0) == typeof(1) :P

Comment: @Alpha `typeof(1/0) == typeof(1.23)` :P

Comment: @M28 `typeof(1) == typeof(1.23)` :P

Comment: @kinokijuf `typeof null == typeof Math`

Comment: @Paul the only know person to fit infinity into an integer is Jon Skeet...

Answer (score 21):

### bc (1 character)

```
9
```

Without a scoring method, this has a fair magnitude/length ratio indeed.

Comment: Yikes, downmodded for that.  It was intended as a joke, and yet... come on, please at least explain why you think the reasoning is invalid.

Comment: +1 (although 99 has a far better magnitude/length ratio)

Comment: Maybe I should say it outright instead of hinting: in its current state the question is subjective and gives us no way to compare answers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor while true, `999` is almost 10 times as good.

Answer (score 17):

#### bash (41)

approx. 10,000,000 digits:

```
ulimit -t 60;while true;do echo -n 5;done
```

Comment: Can save a few characters there: `ulimit -t 60;while :;do printf 5;done` (`true` → `:`, `echo -n` → `printf`).

Answer (score 16):

### Python 18 characters

```
print hex(8**9**9)
```

It's about 290 million digits.

Turns out python `print` of decimal numbers is really slow, but `hex` is fast:

```
> time python -c "print hex(8**9**9)" | wc
   1       1 290565371
real    0m40.514s
```

Comment: Is that going to run in under a minute? Probably not.

Comment: If not, do 8**8**8, or 7**7**7...

Comment: 8**8**9 takes 13 seconds and is 121 million digits.

Comment: Looks like having a power of 2 as the leftmost digit helps a lot, perhaps the python internal implementation of ** takes advantage of sparse bignums.  8**9**9 takes just about a minute to compute, 350M digits.

Comment: `hex` is faster because that skips expensive binary->decimal conversions.

Answer (score 12):

### Ruby - 8 chars

```
p $$**$$
```

260120641601536  digits, today on my system. ($$ is the process ID).

Answer (score 11):

```
while(1){print 1}
```

Time to write is `O(n)` compared to length of output number.

Comment: Surely, writing 9 is always going to be better than writing 1, right? Also, Code Golf 101: always strip out all optional spaces. That means all the spaces around the brackets, in this case.

Comment: I chose 1 just so it sounds nicer when you read it out loud :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Using 9 may turn in a copyright violation of _Revolution 9_ from The Beatles. =P

Comment: @Alpha numbers cannot be copyrighted

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer True. My comment was made in jest, the last characters are a tongue-out emoji denoting joking. Even if they were, that wouldn't apply here since we're just printing characters on an output stream rather than the recording of the track, so they'd be very different pieces in a non-competing space.

Answer (score 10):

### C 86 (including NL)

```
main(i){ 
char b[8<<14];
memset(b,'9',8<<14);
for(i=0;i<8<<15;i++)
write(1,b,8<<14);
}
```

Prints 34_359_973_368 digits on my i7 620M. Challenge this score!

```
$ gcc -O3 a.c; time ./a.out | wc -c 
34359738368

real    0m31.974s
user    0m0.500s
sys     0m41.031s
```

Answer (score 7):

#### bash, 35 chars, unimaginably big number

The question doesn't specify the output representation, so I'm going to go charging far past any of the numbers output by previous answers (and way way way past even Graham's number):

```
for((i=999;i--;))do printf 9→9;done
```

An even shorter answer, although with a smaller number (still larger than Graham's number) is:

(12 chars)

```
echo 3→3→3→3
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? And did you downvote the question too? - because if there's a problem it's there, not here.

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 5

```
10! !
```

10 factorial, factorial.  Prints 22,228,104 digits in about 30 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Why not `99! !` ? Same count. Much larger number.

Comment: @CMP larger numbers do not print in under a minute, and *Mathematica* will not even attempt to fully evaluate `99! !`.

Comment: Sounds fair to me then.

Answer (score 5):

**PHP**

1,500,050,000,000 digits in 53.383 seconds (1.5 trillion digits) in 61 characters:

```
$a=bcpow('1000','10000');for($i=0;$i<50000000;$i++)echo $a;
```

Comment: To what medium are you writing this number at a rate of about 26 GB/s?

Comment: [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) ([it is web scale after all](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1016320617/mongodb-is-web-scale)).

Answer (score 2):

#### LISP (18)

10,000,000 digits in few seconds (SBCL).

```
(expt 10 10000000)
```

Comment: With the same amount of characters, can't you just do `(expt 99 99999999)`?

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure - 28 chars (for unreasonably large numbers)

Strategy is to repeatedly apply the function f(x)=x^x. Works fine because Clojure automatically uses BigInteger arthmetic when this starts to overflow the normal integer range.

```
(nth(iterate #(expt % %)X)Y)
```

Choose X and Y depending on how unreasonably large you want the answer to be and how long you want it to run....:

For X=2:

```
Y=0 -> 2
Y=1 -> 4
Y=2 -> 256
Y=3 -> about 3.2*10^619 (in less than 1ms)
Y=4 -> unreasonably large
```

For X=9:

```
Y=0 -> 9
Y=1 -> 387420489
Y=2 -> about 10^320000000 
Y=3 -> ermmm..... even bigger than unreasonably large?
```

A couple of things to note:

- `(iterate #(expt % %)X)` creates an infinite lazy sequence of ridiculously large exponentials. Y just determines which term of the sequence you want to look at (as you can see above, even the very early terms get very large very fast...)
- if not already imported you need to (use 'clojure.contrib.math) for the expt function

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, 10 characters

```
seq -s9 $$
```

2011.8 digits per code character today on my machine.

Comment: How does it work? `seq --help` says: `-s, --separator=STRING`. $$ is the PID of the current shell. So if it was 3, it would be 19293 - ah - I understand. I would vote it up, if there was an objective winning criteria.

Comment: Nice.  Add a -w for an even higher number.... but since there are no winning criteria, it's impossible to know if that's better or worse

Answer (score 1):

Python: 83 characters, 32,089,643 digit number on my PC in a minute

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1e9)
def p(n):sys.stdout.write(str(n));p(n*9)
p(9)
```

Note that it will either run out of time (in which case kill it) or eventually throw stack overflow errors, so you need to pipe stderr to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows PowerShell(7)

I guess this is cheating, but techncially the value printed *is* an integer:

```
'9'*9e6
```

Exactly 9000000 digits.

Can be made larger with (19):

```
'9'*[int]::MaxValue
```

but raises an OutOfMemoryException on my poor 32-bit machine. This, however, will work fine as long as it's left running:

```
for(){write-host -n 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 115 characters:

```
<? $f=fopen("/tmp/int.txt","w");for($i=$t=0;$i<2.4e7;$i++,$t++){if($t>1e4){fputs($f,$a);$t=0;}$a.=$i;}fputs($f,$a);
```

Outputs at least 1,024,000,00 characters to /tmp/int.txt.

File size (after running): http://codepad.viper-7.com/rgDglK

**Output to Screen, 76 characters**

```
<? for($i=$t=0;$i<2.4e7;$i++,$t++){if($t>1e4){echo $a;$t=0;}$a.=$i;}echo $a;
```

Has the ability to output 208, 896, 814, 305 characters, tested but unconfirmed through the output.  You can confirm it by only calculating the length of the output through the second link.  Each page may require a few refreshes due to errors.

Output: http://codepad.viper-7.com/rJJerv (Will crash the page eventually)
Length: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zWxX0C

Both the file size verification and the length verification take less than a minute on my old laptop, the output verification crashes the brower ~20 seconds into loading.  The question did not state that the script had to work via command line, so I would not expect it to give perfect results when run that way.

Comment: I don't think I can verify your output of 208GB ;)

Comment: Modified the code to a verifiable 1GB, it outputs it to a file for verification.

Answer (score 1):

`alert(Number.MAX_VALUE); : 1.7976931348623157e+308`
`<script>function f(m){n=1;for(i=1;i<=m;i++){n*=i;}return n;}alert(f(f(9)));</script> : Infinity`

Comment: The first isn't an integer and will the second return in 1 minute?

Comment: @marcog, what's the fractional part of 1.7976931348623157e+308 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
time echo "7^7^7" | bc

...
29571409790619889611503701095991663965767866370599610471047901915338\
37220795832889549191447357443319063581523185421788310894001395744859\
694202869611751580402966282378932933502849310357073612870132343

real    0m58.837s
user    0m56.220s
sys 0m0.028s
```

on a 1.6 Mhz Pentium M.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /dev/sda
```

It's a 256-base Integer with 640,135,028,736 digits on my 640GB hd.
Too bad some are non-printable.

Comment: This wouldn't be represented as an Integer and probably not finish wihin 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, lets see, the largest "decimal number" I could generate
on Linux, 2.4GHz Intel/Core2 w/2GB RAM, needing:

```
real    0m51.341s
user    0m1.820s
sys     0m5.644s
```

keeping user time far below 60s.

### Perl, 15 characters

```
print 1,"0"x2e9
```

gives a number staring with **100000...** and with about 2,000,000,000 (2 billion) zeros in total.

Regards

rbo

---

<sub>Tested with</sub>

```
 time perl -e 'print 1,"0"x2e9'>out
```

on a good hard drive.

Comment: You can make it shorter : `say"1"x2e9` (10 char).

Comment: @M42: Or even `say 9x2e9`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Yes, you're right, and `say 9x9e9` produces a longer number.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - 12 chars

**7.5e+306 / character of code**

**25.7 digits / character of code**

```
p 9e307.to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @M28 's answer

**PHP 10 chars**

```
echo 9e999
```

Answer (score 1):

### C

```
printf("-infinity");
```

What's your definition of "large"?

Comment: If you can output a unicode character (wprintf), then just output the '∞' character (U+221E)

Comment: What's your definition of "integer"? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 18

```
<?for(;1;print9){}
```

=D

Comment: `Notice: Use of undefined constant print9 - assumed 'print9' in Command line code on line 1`
Although you'll have to add a space, you can remove the 1 from the foor loop.

Comment: Use a semicolon instead. So: `<?for(;;print 9);`

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 11

`p 9 while 1`

Or you can omit the `9` and pretend that it's outputting in the ascii representation of the number "0x0A0A0A0A..."

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 137 characters

```
USING: calendar kernel io math.order sequences ;
58 seconds hence
99999 "9" <repetition> concat
[ dup write over now after? ] loop 2drop
```

With comments,

```
! calendar => seconds hence now
! kernel => dup over loop 2drop
! io => write
! math.order => after?
! sequences => <repetition> concat
USING: calendar kernel io math.order sequences ;

! Push the stop time (58 seconds after now). This leaves 2 extra seconds
! for starting and stopping the script.
58 seconds hence

! Push a long string of "9"s. The best length is near 99999.
99999 "9" <repetition> concat
[
    ! Write the very long string of "9"s.
    dup write
    ! If the stop time is after now, then loop.
    over now after?
] loop

! Empty the data stack.
2drop
```

This script tries to print as many "9" digits as possible, without exceeding the time limit of one minute. The number of digits changes from run to run.

Output is **10 ^ 4_765_052_349 - 1**, if I must display the number in an *xterm*.

```
$ time ~/park/factor/factor scratch.factor | tee out
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
...
999999999999999999    0m58.56s real     0m15.63s user     0m26.21s system
$ wc -c out
 4765052349 out
```

Output is **10 ^ 22_843_571_562 - 1**, if I never display the number.

```
$ time ~/park/factor/factor scratch.factor | wc -c 
 22843571562
    0m58.32s real     0m50.27s user     0m19.50s system
```

Additional notes:

- Each `write` converts the string (Unicode codepoints) to a byte array (UTF-8). This conversion might waste time inside the loop. A faster program might make a byte array before the loop, and write the byte array inside the loop; but I cannot write a byte array to the default output stream, which is a character stream. I would have to use many characters to open a binary stream.
- A faster program might call *setitimer(2)* and handle *SIGALRM* after 58 seconds. I did not find a short way to call *setitimer(2)* from Factor.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (code: 22 chars, output: 309 digits)

```
main=print$floor 1e309
```

This outputs:
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216

Any higher exponent yields the same result, as 1e309 gets interpreted as Infinity, and this is apperantly the maximum result of `floor`.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (20 characters)

```
main=print.floor$1/0
```

Answer (score 1):

### Brainfuck, 4

Of course the answer is in base 256

```
-[.]
```

C-C after a minute. Will print a number about 255^1e10.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 14 bytes

```
.print for^Inf
```

There is a pattern in this integer. I would name it a waterfall because it looks like one.

Answer (score 0):

**Python, 21 characters**

```
print "10"+"^10"*1337
```

> "output a large integer"

It has 10 to the power of 10 repeated 1336 times ([Tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)) number of zeros with a leading 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows x86 .com**

8 bytes

```
B4 02 B2 39 CD 21 EB F8
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreted Haskell using tryhaskell.org, 10 characters, 5120 digits

```
0xF^0xFFFF
```

Comment: That interpreter seems to truncate the output, which should be the 77076 digits of 15^65535. Notice that 999^999999 also has ten characters and should produce 2999563 digits.