# Largest number in ten bytes of code

Tags: code-challenge, number, busy-beaver

Your goal is to print (to the standard output) the largest number possible, using just ten characters of code.

- You may use any features of your language, except built-in exponentiation functions.

  - Similarly, you may not use scientific notation to enter a number. (Thus, no `9e+99`.)
- The program must print the number without any input from the user. Similarly, no reading from other files, or from the Web, and so on.
- Your program must calculate a single number and print it. You can not print a string, nor can you print the same digit thousands of times.
- You may exclude from the 10-character limit any code necessary to print anything. For example, in Python 2 which uses the `print x` syntax, you can use up to 16 characters for your program.
- The program must actually succeed in the output. If it takes longer than an hour to run on the fastest computer in the world, it's invalid.
- The output may be in any format (so you can print `999`, `5e+100`, etc.)
- [Infinity is an abstract concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity), not a number. So it's not a valid output.

Comment: Did you look at these two?


http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185/print-largest-integer-you-can-with-the-fewest-characters

http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "calculate". Also, `If it takes longer than an hour to run on any computer in the world, it's invalid.` is not objective. I could (theoretically) manufacture a computer that takes an hour to change one T-state

Comment: @user80551 I clarified what I meant by "any".

Comment: @MadTux None of the top answers on those questions are valid here, since they either take millions of years to run, or are way longer than 10 characters.

Comment: Do imports count to the 10 char limit too?

Comment: I've voted to close as "Too broad", for reasons which will be obvious if you read the answers to the first question linked by MadTux above.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, it is getting all sorts of entertaining answers, and the 10-character limit makes things interesting, so I'm beginning to like it.

Comment: Does bit-shift count as an exponentiation operator since it is equivalent to `* 2^x` ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: This is far less broad than that, though. There is actually a scoring criterion (the number), a program criterion (<= 10 chars), and a time limit (< 1 hour running time)

Comment: @Claudiu: "*the output may be in any format*"

Comment: The fact that the time limit depends on the performance of the fastest computer in the world makes it impossible for us to determine the set of valid answers... I don't really like that

Comment: @DavidZ: True. I'd like to see it changed to "1 hour on X computer", and also clarify the rules as to bit-shift, and whether other large built-in functions (e.g. ack in Wolfram) are allowed. I guess not the best question, but I enjoyed playing to the spirit of the rules

Comment: As I see it, the problem with `ack` as used in the current Wolfram answers is that it doesn't *calculate* the result, it just estimates it.

Comment: Are importing the libraries is counted as a code?

Comment: So you want the longest number possible in 10 bytes but not the largest number possible?

Comment: I don't like the rules. I could have posted this `last [1..]`. It extracts the last element of an infinite list.

Comment: @Ypnypn One of the rules currently says, "you may not use scientific notation to enter a number". The rules appear to barely leave open the possibility for our code to use scientific notation inside a *string* literal. Is that so? I suppose `eval("9e9")` still isn't quite as large as `9999999999`.

Comment: Exponentiation functions are not allowed, but ackermann function is allowed? That seems really arbitrary. It remains unclear why a symbolic manipulation is considered "calculating" the number.

Comment: It would be fun to see this for each of 1..10 bytes.

Comment: what about Aceto, where you can do: 9pppppppppppppppp (9 pushes 9 on the stack, and p prints out 9('0'*p)s

Comment: @Dennis It's not an estimate, it's an exact result, but it's a trivial conversion from Ackermann to arrow notation, like taking a square root and turning it into a negative exponent.  Literally, **ack(m,n) = 2 ↑ ⁽ᵐ⁻²⁾ (n+3) - 3**

Comment: -1 for arbitrary Do X Without Y (banning exp), feature assumption (number), subjective validity criteria (an hour on any computer), subjective scoring criteria (the print rule). How did this get 88 upvotes?

Comment: Now I want to know in 9,8,7,6... bytes of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable)

Comment: Note that you can already exceed Graham's Number with a program less than 8 bytes long: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/shortest-terminating-program-whose-output-size-exceeds-grahams-number/219734#comment533337_219734

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Wolfram Language**

```
ack(9!,9!)
```

[Try it online!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ack%289!,9!%29)

$$\text{ack}(9!,9!) = 2 \uparrow^{362878} 362883 - 3$$

Output is in Arrow Notation.

Comment: This goes against the rule that says you can't get it from the Web.

Comment: @KyleKanos It doesn't my interpreter happens to be on the web.
Like some other REPLs.

Comment: Not sure how that's different. Web access is web access, and it's not allowed as per the rules.

Comment: @KyleKanos Its different because the code/program isn't calling out to the web. Other Examples
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground
http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/getting-started

Comment: Pretend you're on a deserted island in the middle of the Pacific Ocean and no internet (and solar powered laptop), can you say definitively that this code of yours will work on your laptop? If yes, then it passes the test & I'm wrong; if no (the case here), then it fails the test & you're wrong.

Comment: @KyleKanos You're changing the rules of the challenge. Where does it say your on a desert island? Does my Laptop have Mathematica. Do I have a raspberry PI?

Comment: It says "no Web access" pretty clearly; your answer says WolframAlpha (a website) explicitly. No further discussion is necessary.

Comment: @KyleKanos It doesn't say "no Web access" any where in the challenge.

Comment: Please read the 2nd bullet point carefully. See also [this answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1085/11376) on loopholes that are not funny.

Comment: The Wolfram Language is available to use an Raspberry Pi and doesn't require web access. So isn't in violation of that rule.

Comment: I think it is very valid answer.  Stupid reasoning for being on island and having no access to internet.  'No web' requirement is only to prevent printing output from a already available resource.  All answers are valid as long as they 'run' a piece of code to calculate the output.  Latest Visual Studio is coming that runs your code on the Azure cloud, so you want to restrict C#?  Or you are ineligible if you have chromebook?

Comment: ``ack(99!,9)`` is much, much larger.

Comment: I think ``9! !~ack~9`` should also work. But I can't test it in WolframAlpha.

Comment: Does it complete within an hour? Can we actually use Arrow notation as the output?

Comment: One of the other answers says that ack(4,2) is the largest he can calculate in an hour so I would be surprised if this did...

Comment: What happened to the time limit?!

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say it's calculating it. Trying doing `ack(9!,9!) + 1` and watch it not even know what's going on — if it were at least keeping things in a symbolic representation, it'd be able to show *something*.  This is basically equivalent to a google search.

Answer (score 126):

## Perl, >1.96835797883262e+18

```
time*time
```

Might not be the largest answer... today! But wait enough millennia and it will be!

---

**Edit:**

To address some of the comments, by "enough millenia," I do in fact mean n<sup>100s</sup> of years.

To be fair, if the big freeze/heat death of the universe is how the universe will end (estimated to occur ~10<sup>100</sup> years), the "final" value would be ~10<sup>214</sup>, which is certainly much less than some of the other responses (though, "random quantum fluctuations or quantum tunneling can produce another Big Bang in 10<sup>10<sup>56</sup></sup> years"). If we take a more optimistic approach (e.g. a cyclic or multiverse model), then time will go on infinitely, and so some day in some universe, on some high-bit architecture, the answer would exceed some of the others.

On the other hand, as pointed out, `time` is indeed limited by the size of integer/long, so in reality something like `~0` would always produce a larger number than `time` (i.e. the max `time` supported by the architecture).

This wasn't the most serious answer, but I hope you guys enjoyed it!

Comment: Upvoted because I like the eventuality

Comment: Won't `time` wrap around and return a small number at some point? Depends on whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit perl I guess

Comment: @AllenG: Where does perl get the data source for `time` from? If it's from the system which uses unsigned ints, then it will wrap around.

Comment: Right, I misinterpreted the comment. Well, hopefully by the time the universe is ready, computers/Perl will have increased the size of their integers :).

Comment: Wait, reading the clock doesn't count as an input? We can do that? I guess I'll exploit it after all.

Comment: 1000 years ~ 3e10 seconds, so you'll still be hovering around 1e21 as your output. Perhaps if you waited 1e50 years, you might start competing against the other answers?

Comment: That’s only 9 characters, why not `time**time`?

Comment: @Timwi : Exponentiation operators not allowed

Comment: Do you pronounce this "time times time"? :-) (hi Timwi!)

Comment: Is the time on death heat of the universe accounting for daylight savings? You could earn a few more seconds of existence.

Comment: Eventually when the big freeze occurs this answer won't be so relevant anymore

Answer (score 66):

## Wolfram ≅ 2.003529930 × 10<sup>19728</sup>

Yes, it's a language! It drives the back-end of the popular Wolfram Alpha site. 
It's the only language I found where the Ackermann function is built-in **and** abbreviated to less than 6 characters.

In eight characters:

```
$ ack(4,2)

200352993...719156733
```

Or ≅ 2.003529930 × 10<sup>19728</sup>

`ack(4,3)`, `ack(5,2)` etc. are much larger, but too large. `ack(4,2)` is probably the largest Ackermann number than can be completely calculated in under an hour.

Larger numbers are rendered in symbolic form, e.g.:

```
$ ack(4,3)

2↑²6 - 3 // using Knuth's up-arrow notation
```

The rules say any output format is allowed, so this might be valid. This is greater than 10<sup>10<sup>19727</sup></sup>, which is larger than any of the other entries here except for the repeated factorial.

However,

```
$ ack(9,9)

2↑⁷12 - 3
```

is larger than the repeated factorial. The largest number I can get in ten characters is:

```
$ ack(99,99)

2↑⁹⁷102 - 3
```

This is insanely huge, the Universe isn't big enough to represent a significant portion of its digits, even if you took repeated logs of the number.

Comment: Why does the exponent look weird? Is it `10 ^ 19278`  or something else?

Comment: Not bad, but it's no match for my `ack(4,2)+1` solution.

Comment: ack(4,2)+2, I WIN

Comment: Is the source available for the Wolfram language?

Comment: @Claudiu - Superscripts 1-3 are in a different UNICODE block from 0,4-9. Automatic font substitution tries to match the fonts but can't always.

Comment: @KyleKanos - No, you have to pay for it. It's used in Mathematica, too.

Comment: I think you won.

Comment: _"As large as it is, Graham's number surpasses anything expressible as an Ackermann number."_ Counter-example: `ack(g_64, g_64)`. BOOM

Comment: @ColeJohnson: as far as I know, there is only one meaning of the word 'source' when it comes to programming languages.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: except my question was precise: is the source of the Wolfram language available. It is very hard to misinterpret that to mean something about a calculation.

Comment: @Kyle Well, there's a free interpreter available online. :P

Comment: @Yimin Mathematica actually makes a server call to WolframAlpha when you do an `=` line.

Comment: @Riking: the free one online is not allowed for this competition though.

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's like saying you can express g_64 using addition, and then saying g_64+0! Boom! The reasoning is ultimately circular.

Comment: @Kyle, Yimin There are lots of misleading statements in this post and the comments under it.  This is *not* the Wolfram Language, and *not* what's used as the backend of W|A.  It is simply "natural language" input to Wolfram|Alpha. In the Wolfram Language `ack(4,2)` is invalid input.  W|A's natural language input shouldn't even count as a programming language.  It is not Turing complete, and you can't write even basic programs in it such as Euclid's algorithm.  For this reason I don't think this is a valid answer any more than a Google query would be.

Comment: The Wolfram Language is the programming language used in Mathematica, documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/).  Wolfram|Alpha takes natural language as input, not the Wolfram Language.

Comment: @Cruncher except that you _can_. Graham's number _is_ a computable number unlike Chaitlin's constant (which is an _uncomputable_ number). How about a googolplex (10^googol)? It's a _computable_ number, but it's so massive we won't be able to store it. Computability of a number _isn't_ based off how big it is. Graham's number is _orders_ of magnitude larger than a googolplex, but _it's still computable_. As such, I can use it in numerical formula calculations.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Expressible and Computable are two very different concepts

Comment: @Cruncher from the question: "Your program must _calculate_ a single number..." As in computable numbers. I really don't get what your getting at.

Comment: @ColeJohnson not even really talking about the question. Just responding to "Counter-example: ack(g_64, g_64). BOOM" which was in response to "As large as it is, Graham's number surpasses anything expressible as an Ackermann number."

Comment: @Cruncher and I'm saying that if your Ackermann number is generated with Graham's number in both arguments, it will be bigger than Graham's number. i.e. `A[g_64, g_64] > g_64`

Comment: The only problem with this language is that it melts at 3695 degrees Kelvin.

Answer (score 30):

## Python2 shell, 3,010,301 digits

```
9<<9999999
```

Calculating the length: Python will append a "L" to these long numbers, so it reports 1 character more than the result has digits.

```
>>> len(repr( 9<<9999999 ))
3010302
```

First and last 20 digits:

```
40724177878623601356... ...96980669011241992192
```

Comment: Darn it! This showed up whilst I was writing the same answer

Comment: That's really just `9 * 2**9999999`, so one could argue it uses exponentiation.

Comment: Wait, `***built-in*** exponentiation functions` are not allowed so this *might* slip under the rules. +1

Comment: Mathematical way of computing the length: [`floor(log10(9 * 2**9999999))+1`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28log10%289+*+2**9999999%29%29%2B1)

Comment: @Quincunx: Yes... because showing the length is no proof for really having calculated the number I added 40 digits of it. If needed I can add a shasum or something similar too...

Comment: @Quincunx It does calculate it, but printing would take a **long** time. Actually, I couldn't get to make it a string on my machine. See http://pastebin.com/PDTc28P3

Comment: It's pretty slow in CPython, but in PyPy it should calculate in a few minutes. If you just want to verify the length, it's quicker to calculate `floor(log10(9) + log10(2) * 9999999) + 1`.

Comment: 9<<(9<<99) is a lot bigger, if it terminates.

Comment: @KeithRandall: Yes! I am playing with it already. Or to be mor precise: Waiting. Calculating this terminates relatively quickly... try printing it in hexadecimal instead of decimal, that's a lot faster and gives a number of more than 280megabytes of "hex-digits". If I get it printed in decimal I'll mention it here. More than `9<<27` as argument to `<<` is rejected by python. Maybe some other language will accept more there... :-(

Comment: Got no luck with `9<<(9<<99)` up to now: sdf.org rebooted while my calculation was running (nice 19, I wasn't mean!) and on sdfeu.org it got a kill signal after lots of hours, maybe piping the output into `xz -9e >outfile` was failing (`xz -9e` may have been too much of a RAM hog?). I've one more job running on an old notebook (I'm on the road with not much cpu-power)... patience... ommmmmmmmmmmmm... ;-)

Comment: @yeti It sounds like you are basically describing my answer, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/largest-number-in-ten-bytes-of-code/31756#31756

Comment: @isaacg: (a): I am trying to get it printed in decumal because printing in hex is no big deal. And (b): I have no Python3 at hand right now, so i'm stuck with `9<<27` as maximum argument to `9<<X`. So don't worry: It is different from your answer in two aspects! At least until weekend... when I'm back in my home compouting center, things will look different... mwhuaahahaahahahahahahahahahhahahahahahaaaaa!

Answer (score 29):

## CJam, 2 × 10<sup>268,435,457</sup>

```
A28{_*}*K*
```

This computes *b*, defined as follows:

- a<sub>0</sub> = 10
- a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n - 1</sub><sup>2</sup>
- b = 20 × a<sub>28</sub>

```
$ time cjam <(echo 'A28{_*}*K*') | wc -c
Real    2573.28
User    2638.07
Sys     9.46
268435458
```

#### Background

This follows the same idea as [Claudiu's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31718), but it isn't based on it. I had a similar idea which I posted [just a few minutes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/31713/3) after [he posted his](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/31718/3), but I discarded it since it didn't come anywhere near the time limit.

However, [aditsu's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/largest-number-in-ten-digits-of-code/31718?noredirect=1#comment66589_31713) to upgrade to Java 8 and [my idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/largest-number-in-ten-digits-of-code/31718?noredirect=1#comment66575_31718) of using powers of 10 allowed CJam to calculate numbers beyond the reach of GolfScript, which seems to be due to some bugs/limitations of Ruby's Bignum.

#### How it works

```
A    " Push 10.                                                          ";
28{  " Do the following 28 times:                                        ";
  _* " Duplicate the integer on the stack and multiply it with its copy. ";
}*   "                                                                   ";
K*   " Multiply the result by 20.                                        ";
```

---

## CJam, ≈ 8.1 × 10<sup>1,826,751</sup>

```
KK,{)*_*}/
```

Takes less than five minutes on my machine, so there's still room for improvement.

This computes a<sub>20</sub>, defined as follows:

- a<sub>0</sub> = 20
- a<sub>n</sub> = (n × a<sub>n - 1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

#### How it works

```
KK,   " Push 20 [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ]. ";
{     " For each integer in the array:                                 ";
  )*  " Increment it and compute the its product with the accumulator. ";
  _*  " Multiply the result with itself.                               ";
}/
```

Comment: Haha, is that Kirby? :)

Comment: Could you describe what this is doing?

Comment: FYI, I ran some tests to check BigInteger performance - I calculated 100000! and converted to string. Results: java 6: 21 sec calculation, 44 sec toString; java 7: 14 sec calculation, 42 sec toString; java 8: 5 sec calculation, 1 sec toString!

Comment: @aditsu: Upgrading Java reduced the runtime from 5 minutes to 2 seconds!

Answer (score 21):

## Any language with short enough constant names, 18 digits approx.

```
99/sin(PI)
```

I would post this as a PHP answer but sadly `M_PI` makes this just a little too long! But PHP yields 8.0839634798317E+17 for this. Basically, it abuses the lack of absolute precision in PI :p

Comment: Can't you do tan(PI/2)?

Comment: @user80551 Could do, but I just noticed that I could make use of that last remaining character in the limit to boost my result by 99 times.

Comment: Too long in Common Lisp: `(/ 99(sin pi))` (14 characters). Error in TI-83: `99/sin(π` (8 characters) causes division by zero. Works in **LibreOffice Calc**: `=99/SIN(PI(` (10 characters, not counting `=`) computes 808423047055000000. LibreOffice auto-inserts the last two `))` in `=99/SIN(PI())`.

Comment: It's depending on the precision of the language. In PHP 14 decimal digits is a common value.

Comment: @kernigh It doesn't matter in this case, but would `99/sin(π` be five bytes or eight? I know TI-BASIC stores a bunch of commands as single bytes; is `sin(` one of them?

Comment: @WChargin `sin(` acts like one character, but I know not many bytes. See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/how-to-score-ti-basic

Comment: You can do this in [Clip](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip) v4 or higher (though I can't find an interpreter for any such version)  with only 6 chars: `/99.sP`.

Comment: This reminds me of a time I took a series that involved `tan(pi/2)` or something similar in Wolfram.  When the calculations get rough, Wolfram approximates, and it has *very* long approximations of `pi` handy.

Comment: @bcsb1001 then I suppose that can be boosted higher

Comment: `PHP_INT_MAX` sadly is 11 chars

Comment: `PHP_INT_MAX = 9223372036854775807`

Comment: `sin(pi)^-9 = 1.6081E+143`

Answer (score 21):

## Python 3, 9*2^(7*2^33) > 10^18,100,795,813

## <strike>9*2^(2^35) > 10^10,343,311,894</strike>

Edit: 
My new answer is:

```
9<<(7<<33)
```

Old answer, for posterity:

```
9<<(1<<35)
```

Ten characters exactly.

I am printing the number in hex, and

> You may exclude from the 10-character limit any code necessary to print anything. For example, in Python 2 which uses the print x syntax, you can use up to 16 characters for your program.

Therefore, my actual code is:

```
print(hex(9<<(7<<33)))
```

Proof that it runs in the specified time and generates a number of the specified size:

```
time python bignum.py > bignumoutput.py

real    10m6.606s
user    1m19.183s
sys    0m59.171s
wc -c bignumoutput.py 
15032385541 bignumoutput.py
```

My number > 10^(15032385538*log(16)) > 10^18100795813

3 less hex digits than the above wc printout because of the initial `0x9`.

Python 3 is necessary because in python 2, `7<<33` would be a long, and `<<` doesn't take longs as inputs.

I can't use 9<<(1<<36) instead because:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bignum.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(hex(9<<(1<<36)))
MemoryError
```

Thus, this is the largest possible number of the form `a<<(b<<cd)` printable on my computer.

In all likelihood, the fastest machine in the world has more memory than I do, so my alternate answer is:

```
9<<(9<<99)
```

9*2^(9*2^99) > 10^(1.7172038461*10^30)

However, my current answer is the largest anyone has submitted, so it's probably good enough. Also, this is all assuming bit-shifting is allowable. It appears to be, from the other answers using it.

Comment: So far this looks to be the largest answer by far. It's a 10,000,000,000 digit number, after all.

Comment: @nneonneo : I believe my solution is larger :)

Comment: Your alternate answer requires _juuuuust_ less than 1 MiYiB of memory, and requires 100 bits of addressable memory (so it won't work until at least 128-bit Python). (Source: [my similar answer](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109542/43394))

Answer (score 19):

## **HTML, 9999999999**

```
9999999999
```

.. nailed it.

Comment: not a programming language, though.

Comment: Use PHP, it's better!

Comment: @cat In this case, it's fine, as this is reminiscent of kolmogorov complexity challenges.

Comment: `9&Hat;9999` prints `9^9999`. Just sayin :)

Comment: saddly `PHP_INT_MAX` is 11

Answer (score 17):

## Haskell

Without any tricks:

```hs
main = print -- Necessary to print anything
    $9999*9999 -- 999890001
```

Arguably without calculating anything:

```hs
main = print
    $floor$1/0 -- 179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

Adapting [Niet's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/largest-number-in-ten-digits-of-code/31711#31711):

```hs
main = print
    $99/sin pi -- 8.083963479831708e17
```

Comment: Third bullet says "Your program must **calculate**..."

Comment: `floor(infinity)` is a finite number? What the heck Haskell?

Comment: 1/0 != infinity, it's undefined.

Comment: Are you sure about that, @ckuhn203? In both GHC 7.6.3 and 7.8.2, I get `isInfinite $ 1 / 0 -- True`. As far as I can tell, [IEEE 754 defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Exception_handling) `1 / 0` as infinity.

Comment: I'm absolutely positive about it @TaylorFausak. Just because IEEE defined it that way, doesn't make it true. [See this answer on Math Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/61391/155159).

Comment: Oh, you mean mathematically. I agree completely. But as far as programming with IEEE floating point (and Haskell in particular) is concerned, `1 / 0 == Infinity`.

Comment: @ckuhn203 The IEEE convention is correct in the sense that the reciprocal of any sequence that tends to 0 tends to infinity.

Comment: Why do you include `$` in the code?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy without the `$` I would have to use parentheses for grouping, which would take an extra character. So my first answer could only have been `main=print(9999*999)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521246/what-does-mean-do-in-haskell for more about `$` in Haskell.

Comment: Can't `$` be included in the print boilerplate?

Comment: No. It's not necessary to "print anything". You can do `main=print"hello"` without the `$` or parentheses.

Comment: And why is `$floor$0/0` so big? Even bigger than everything here, as far as magnitude.

Comment: I like the 1/0 trick. Nice and big!

Comment: `$cosh 710` is good for `1.1169973830808557e308`, if we eschew the exponential definition in favor of the more fundamental geometric definition.

Answer (score 16):

### Powershell - 1.12947668480335E+42

```
99PB*9E9PB
```

Multiplies 99 Pebibytes times 9,000,000,000 Pebibytes.

Comment: 98901 sq petabytes? Is that some sort of method to measure the surface bit density of (future high-capacity)hard-disks?

Comment: Oh, nice. Didn't know pebibytes were possible by now. I always thought it stopped at tebibytes.

Comment: @Joey Now if MS would only hurry up and add yobibytes, the answer could be even better.

Comment: I could add that to [Pash](https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash) if it helps ... ;-)

Comment: 1+"1"*309 outputs 1.1111e308 though I suppose this breaks the spirit, if not the word of the rule on printing characters. It's cast to a double for output.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use `9E9`.

Answer (score 14):

## J (`((((((((9)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!`)

Yeah, that's a lot. `10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^6.269498812196425)))))))` to be not very exact.

```
!!!!!!!!9x
```

Comment: Can't that be mathematically expressed as `9!!!!!!!!`?

Comment: @TheRare afaik 9!! = 9*7*5*3*1, whereas (9!)! is a lot more!

Comment: @Flonk Really? My calculator says `9!! = 362880!`.

Comment: @TheRare http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%21%21

Comment: @TheRare it's called the double factorial! I think `!!` is a weird choice for a mathematical operator aswell, but that's how it is.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: @Synthetica As my studies in J are... incomplete, what does the `x` do?

Comment: @TheRare It uses arbitrary precision integers: the 64 bit ones J uses normally would overflow, otherwise this expression would result in `_` (infinity)

Comment: @Flonk Wow, I've never heard about that.

Comment: @Synthetica Since `The output may be in any format` , using `_` for infinity might be valid.

Comment: @user80551 It feels against the spirit of the question. It might be technically valid though.

Comment: Does it actually output the number? Is there a free J compiler out there?

Comment: I [did find a compiler](http://www.jsoftware.com/), but after 20 minutes, `!!9x` hasn't printed anything to screen. I sincerely doubt that `!!!!!!!!9x` will *ever* be computed.

Comment: Does it use built-in exponentiation? If yes, I don't think this example is valid the same as mine.

Comment: My previous comment makes a lot of sense since `(9!)!` is a number that has [over 90k digits to it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%289%21%29%21).

Comment: "If it takes longer than an hour to run on the fastest computer in the world, it's invalid." Not sure this would be valid since it doesn't run within an hour

Comment: @kenorb: ! is the factorial function, it's straight multiplication.

Comment: It took 70 minutes, but `!!9x` finally printed to screen. I'm impressed that it actually computed the value, but it still completely fails bullet 5.

Comment: Considering that `((9!)!)!` is [about `10^(10^6.269498812196425)` digits long](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log10%28%28%289%21%29%21%29%21%29), even `!!!9x` probably will never be printed to a screen. However, the program might end up finishing computing it. @KyleKanos It's likely that the reason why it took so long for `!!9x` is because it is ~`10^6.269497348270999` digits long, so the outputting it takes a lot longer. The program probably finished computing the number long before 70 minutes.

Comment: @Quincunx: Likely true, however the condition for a valid answer is that the program must succeed in output; this answer completely fails that criterion. Sadly, the upvoters have neglected all the comments pointing this out and still upvote it over the CJam & Golfscript answers that are insanely huge *and* compute in reasonable time.

Comment: @KyleKanos Not what I meant. I meant to agree with you. I was saying that this program will **never** be able to print the number, so it was invalid. I presented that it might be able to compute it, but not print it.

Comment: @Quincunx: I think I skipped the last half of your first sentence :$.

Comment: @KyleKanos 70 minutes is within an order of magnitude for this comp. If you can find someone with a faster computer I'd call that a valid answer. Would it be winning?

Comment: @curiousdannii: Seeing how there are a few different answers that compute numbers larger than `(9!)!~1e1,859,933`, I don't think this would win, even if it computed that within the hour requirement.

Comment: Why use `!!!!9x` when you can use `!^:!9x`? You're already tossing out the time restriction, so why not go all out?

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't print out the answer.

Answer (score 14):

## [K/Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona): <s>8.977649e261</s> 1.774896e308

```
*/1.6+!170
```

- `!170` creates a vector of numbers from 0 to 169
- `1.6+` adds one to each element of the vector & converts to reals (range is 1.6 to 170.6)
- `*/` multiplies each element of the array together

If Kona supported quad precision, I could do `*/9.+!999` and get around 1e2584. Sadly, it doesn't and I'm capped to double precision.

---

old method

```
*/9.*9+!99
```

- `!99` creates a vector of numbers from 0 to 98
- `9+` adds 9 to each element of the vector (now ranges 9 to 107)
- `9.*` multiplies each element by 9.0 (implicitly converting to reals, so 81.0 through 963.0)
- `*/` multiplies each element of the vector together

Answer (score 11):

## Python - Varies, up to 13916486568675240 (so far)

Not entirely serious but I thought it would be kinda fun.

```
print id(len)*99
```

Out of all the things I tried, `len` was most consistently getting me large ids.

Yielded 13916486568675240 (17 digits) on my computer and 13842722750490216 (also 17 digits) on [this site](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php). I suppose it's possible for this to give you as low as 0, but it could also go higher.

Comment: Great idea but unfortunately it doesn't `calculate` anything.

Comment: I do believe the `*99` part invokes a calculation.

Comment: Oh yes, /me feels stupid now.

Comment: If you use something shorter - say `id(id)` or `id(0j)`, you can multiply by `999`

Comment: @gnibbler id(1) works too.

Comment: Out of smaller named ones in https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html , `vars` consistently gives the highest value(but 4 chars) followed by `sum`. Use `print(sorted([(id(x),x)for x in[id,len,max,min,str,int,ord,chr,sum,map,abs,all,any,bin,bool,eval,oct,vars,iter,list,set,repr,round,zip,type,pow,dict,dir,hex]])[::-1])` to check.

Comment: Why `*99`? Why not `**9`?

Comment: @Trimsty, ** is the built in exponent calculation, forbidden by bullet point 1

Comment: @user80551 `map` followed by `zip` consistently gives the highest value in my interpreter (CPython 3.9 64-bit)

Answer (score 10):

## Golfscript, 1e+33,554,432

```
10{.*}25*
```

Computes `10 ^ (2 ^ 25)`, without using exponents, runs in 96 seconds:

```
$ time echo "10{.*}25*" | ruby golfscript.rb  > BIG10

real    1m36.733s
user    1m28.101s
sys     0m6.632s
$ wc -c BIG10
 33554434 BIG10
$ head -c 80 BIG10
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
$ tail -c 80 BIG10
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It can compute up to `9 ^ (2 ^ 9999)`, if only given enough time, but incrementing the inner exponent by one makes it take ~triple the time, so the one hour limit will be reached pretty soon.

**Explanation**:

Using a previous version with the same idea:

```
8{.*}25*
```

Breaking it down:

```
8         # push 8 to the stack
{...}25*  # run the given block 25 times
```

The stack at the start of each block consists of one number, the current number. This starts off as `8`. Then:

```
.         # duplicate the top of the stack, stack is now | 8 | 8 |
*         # multiply top two numbers, stack is now       | 64 |
```

So the stack, step by step, looks like this:

```
8
8 8
64
64 64
4096
4096 4096
16777216
16777216 16777216
```

... etc. Written in math notation the progression is:

```
n=0, 8                     = 8^1  = 8^(2^0)
n=1, 8*8                   = 8^2  = 8^(2^1)
n=2, (8^2)*(8^2) = (8^2)^2 = 8^4  = 8^(2^2)
n=3,               (8^4)^2 = 8^8  = 8^(2^3)
n=4,               (8^8)^2 = 8^16 = 8^(2^4)
```

Comment: What's the deal with the two one's in front of the 2564 in your output?

Comment: @KyleKanos: That's not my output, it's the output of `wc`. I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: you could use `wc -c` to make the output clearer

Comment: Nice! I had the same idea a few minutes ago, but it runs much slower with CJam (which is surprising, since it's faster than GolfScript in general).

Comment: Isn't that using built-in exponentiation?

Comment: @YiminRong: no, it's using multiplication and looping, I just described the answer using `^` to make it more clear what the program was doing

Comment: *Could* you describe what's going on to those *not* familiar with Golfscript? :D

Comment: @Dennis It seems that java's BigInteger is pretty slow :( I don't know about ruby, but I tested a python program that calculates a factorial and it was significantly faster

Comment: @KyleKanos: Sure! Updated

Comment: Holy crapola that's awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should be 30 *million* digits, not *billion*.

Comment: @Dennis: Oops, I got over-excited. Thanks.

Comment: Minor improvement: `10{.*}25` delivers 33,554,434 digits and finishes in 90 second on my machine. I don't know why, but `10{.*}26*` prints nothing.

Comment: @Dennis: Oh interesting, I guess multiply by powers of 10 is way more efficient for whatever reason .. I got 36 seconds for `10^(2^24)`

Comment: @Dennis: Interesting I found the same (`26*` ran for 40 minutes with no output, yet 25 ran in 2 minutes). maybe we found a bug in teh ruby codes

Answer (score 7):

## [wxMaxima](http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/) ~3x10<sup>49,948</sup> (or 10<sup>8,565,705,514</sup> )

```
999*13511!
```

Output is

```
269146071053904674084357808139[49888 digits]000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

Not sure if it quite fits specs (particularly the output format one), but I can hit even larger:

```
bfloat(99999999!)
```

Output is

```
9.9046265792229937372808210723818b8565705513
```

That's roughly 10<sup>8,565,705,514</sup> which is *significantly* larger than most of the top answers and was computed in about 2 seconds. The `bfloat` function gives [arbitrary precision](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/intromax/intromax.html).

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 4950

Aww man, that's not a lot! 10 characters start after the dollar sign.

```hs
main=putStr.show$sum[1..99]
```

Comment: Why not just [`print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print)? Also, `9/0.000001` is greater than `sum[1..99]`.

Comment: At that rate, we might consider 9 999 999 999 to be a lower bound on results.

Comment: @TaylorFausak This answer is obviously not to be taken seriously!

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 2.174188391646043*10^20686623745

```
$MaxNumber
```

Ten characters exactly.

Comment: Is it technically calculating anything, and is it outputting all the digits and not just scientific notation?

Comment: @Yimin: The output may be in any format (so you can print 999, 5e+100, etc.)

Comment: The value is not set at compile-time, but depends on the particular machine on which the command is run. I think it counts.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1.79769e308 (float64) or 9.99999e6144 (decimal128), 3 bytes

This is the minimum reduction of an empty list:

```apl
⌊/⍬
```

`⌊` minimum

`/` reduction

`⍬` empty list

When reducing an empty list, APL will return the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of the function used (if known). For minimum reduction of a system without infinities (e.g. ISO APL, to which Dyalog APL adheres), the identity element for minimum is the largest representable number:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jni79R71rQJz/aQA) (IEEE 754 64-bit floating-point)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qW9CjtgmGRhbmXI862tP@P@rp0n/Uu@Y/kPM/DQA) (IEEE 754-2008 128-bit decimal floating-point)

Answer (score 6):

## Casio fx-350 ES PLUS, approx. 9.999882753E99

Do calculators count?

[image]

At `70!` the calculator throws error because apparently it has a number range limit `-1E100 ~ 1E100`

Comment: I... don't think this counts as a programming language?

Comment: Well I guess there's another calculator answer so this is probably fine.

Answer (score 6):

## Binary Lambda Calculus, \$ f_{\omega+2} (2)\$, 9.75 bytes

This program outputs a number larger than Graham's Number while using 78 bits, which is 9.75 bytes, within the 10-byte budget given to me:

```
010101000001110011101000000101011000000101101101011010000110100000011100111010
```

If you prefer an ASCII display of the binary number, here it is:

```
T��mhh:
```

(Inspired, but not copied, by the entry mentioned [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83873/theoretically-output-grahams-number))

### How it works:

This Binary Lambda Calculus expression encodes the following expression below:

```
(\f x.f (f x))(\f n.n (\g m.m g m) f n)(\x.x x)(\f x.f (f x))
```

This Lambda Calculus expression uses [Church Numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals). Church Numerals are generally considered to be the standard representation of natural numbers. What makes Church Numerals powerful is that they are defined using recursion:

`[n] f m = f (f (f (...(f m)...)))` with n f's.

What this means is that if we have a function \$f\$ and a natural number \$n\$, we can simply concatenate them into \$n f\$ to make a much faster function. You can read the article I linked above if you want to see how Church Numerals can be encoded in Lambda Calculus.

#### Exponentiation

What is more, Church Numerals can even act on themselves! `n m` represents \$m^n\$ using exponentiation!

Example: \$2^3\$

(Here, we will apply that to the function f n, to show the true power of recursion)

- `3 2 f n`
- `2 (2 (2 f)) n`
- `(2 (2 f)) ((2 (2 f)) n)`
- `(2 f) ((2 f) ((2 f) ((2 f) n)))`
- `f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f n)))))))`
- `= 8 f n`

We can create a function that captures the true power of exponentiation!

```
\x.x x
```

When applied to a Church Numeral \$n\$, it returns \$n^n\$. Viola! Let's call our exponential combinator \$E\$, such that:

```
E = (\x.x x)
```

#### Recursion

In order to get beyond exponentiation, we must recurse our \$E\$ combinator. Remember how popping a number before a function recurses it? Well, we can do this with the E combinator, provided that it is a unary function. Define the \$R\$ combinator as followed:

```
R = (\g. \m.m g m)
```

Here, how it works is that for a function \$f\$ applied to an number \$n\$, \$Rfn\$ reduces down to \$nfn\$. This is awesome, because Church numerals naturally recurse functions, meaning \$nfn\$ reduces down to \$f (f (f ...(f n)...))\$.

What if we let our function be our exponential combinator \$E\$? \$REn\$ grows tetrationally. But there is no reason to stop here. We can merge \$R\$ and \$E\$ into a single combinator, \$(RE)\$, and recurse that to have \$R(RE)n\$. This grows pentationally.

We can have \$R(R(RE))n\$, \$R(R(R(RE)))n\$, and so on. But notice how the \$R\$ combinator is being recursed over \$E\$. Well, this is where Church Numeral Recursion comes back into play.

#### Super-Recursion

Define a new combinator, \$S\$, as the following:

```
S = (\f n.n R f n) = (\f n.n (\g m.m g m) f n)
```

Cool, now one thing that makes this powerful is that while the \$R\$ combinator recurses over a function \$f\$, the \$S\$ combinator repeatedly applies the \$R\$ combinator to a function \$f\$. Consider this:

$$SE3$$

The first thing that \$S\$ combinator is going to do is to reduce to \$nR\$ where n is the number after the \$E\$. So our reduction will look like this:

$$3RE3$$

The Church Numeral recursion applies on \$R\$ over \$E\$, thus nesting \$R\$ three times, thus giving us this:

$$R(R(RE))3$$

As we seen above, each \$R\$ increases the size of the number considerably, and now the \$S\$ combinator recurses over the \$R\$ combinator! The combinator (SE) grows at \$f_{\omega}\$ in the Fast Growing Hierarchy, about the limit of the Ackermann Function. We can take this a step forward.

- \$R(SE)\$ recurses over the (SE) combinator, growth rate similar to Graham's Number
- \$R(R(SE))\$ has \$f_{\omega+2}\$ growth in the fast growing hierarchy
- \$S(SE)\$ has \$f_{\omega2}\$ growth in the fast growing hierarchy
- \$S(S(SE))\$ has \$f_{\omega3}\$ growth in the fast growing hierarchy

Similar to how inserting a church numeral before \$R\$ can recurse the recursion function over \$E\$, inserting a church numeral before \$S\$ recurse the super-recursion function over \$E\$. For example, \$2SE\$ = \$S(SE)\$.

### The Number:

The number is \$2SE2\$ using Church Numerals and the combinators defined above. This translates to about \$f_{\omega+2} (2)\$ in the Fast Growing Hierarchy, which is greater than Graham's Number. Graham's Number is far greater than even \$Ack(9!,9!)\$ in Wolfram-Alpha. Expanding \$2SE2\$ will yield:

```
(\f x.f (f x))(\f n.n (\g m.m g m) f n)(\x.x x)(\f x.f (f x))
```

The lambda expression for \$2\$ is `(\f x.f (f x))`, as you can see it is a Church Numeral. By decoding this Lambda Calculus Expression in [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Binary_lambda_calculus), one could expect a 9.75-byte expression:

```
010101000001110011101000000101011000000101101101011010000110100000011100111010
```

We proved that we can beat Graham's Number in 10 bytes! Ridiculous?

Comment: `(\t. t t S E t) 3 -> 3 3 S E 3 -> 27 S E 3` this reaches $f_{\omega27}(3)$ using 79 bits: `0100010101011010000001010110000001011011010110100001101010000001110011100111010`

Answer (score 5):

## Python shell, <strike>649539</strike> 999890001

Beats Haskell, not really a serious answer.

```
99999*9999
```

Comment: 9999999999 is larger, isn't it?

Comment: @MadTux There is an ambiguous restriction to `calculate` the answer.

Comment: If this answer is correct, then mine `9**9**9**9` is correct either, as it's arithmetic operator (not built-in func).

Comment: @kenorb It's built in ***exponentiation*** that's not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather post this as a comment above, but apparently I can't since I'm a noob.

Python:

`9<<(2<<29)`

I'd go with a larger bit shift, but Python seems to want the right operand of a shift to be a non-long integer.  I think this gets closer to the theoretical max:

`9<<(7<<27)`

The only problem with these is that they might not satisfy rule 5.

Answer (score 4):

### Befunge-93 (1,853,020,188,851,841)

Glad nobody has done Befunge yet (it's my niche), but dammit I can't find any clever trick to increase the number.

```
9:*:*:*:*.
```

So it's 9^16.

```
:*
```

Basically multiplies the value at the top of the stack with itself. So, value at the top of the stack goes:

```
9
81
6561
43046721
1853020188851841
```

and

```
.
```

Outputs the final value.
I would be interested to see if anybody has any better ideas.

Comment: [I have a better idea](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109356/62574)

Answer (score 4):

### At least Python 3.5.0 (64-bit), more than 10^242944768872896860

```
print("{:x}".format( 9<<(7<<60) ))
```

In an ideal world, this would be `9<<(1<<63)-1`, but there aren't enough bytes for that. This number is so big that it requires almost 1 EiB of memory to hold it, which is a little bit more than I have on my computer. Luckily, you only need to use around 0.2% of the world's storage space as swap to hold it. The value in binary is `1001` followed by 8070450532247928832 zeros.

If Python comes out for 128-bit machines, the maximum would be `9<<(9<<99)`, which requires less than 1 MiYiB of memory. This is good, because you'd have enough addressable space left to store the Python interpreter and the operating system.

Comment: "Only 0.2% of the world's storage space"

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart If you think it's good, why not upvote?

Comment: There's your double upvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab (1.7977e+308)

Matlab stores the value of the largest (double-precision) floating-point number in a variable called `realmax`. Invoking it in the command window (or at the command line) prints its value:

```
>> realmax

ans =

  1.7977e+308
```

Comment: Since the OP asked to return a _calculated_ value, you should put `realmax+1`. I tried it for fun and surprise it returns exactly the same number than you have (then I laughed when I realized ... `eps(realmax)=1.99584030953472e+292` ).

Answer (score 3):

## Python, ca. 1.26e1388

```python
9<<(9<<9L)
```

Gives:

> 126026689735396303510997749074166929355794746000200933374690887068497279540873057344588851620847941756785436041299246554387020554314993586209922882758661017328592694996553929727854519472712351667110666886882465827559219102188617052626543482184096111723688960246772278895906137468458526847698371976335253039032584064081316325315024075215490091797774136739726784527496550151562519394683964055278594282441271759517280448036277054137000457520739972045586784011500204742714066662771580606558510783929300569401828194357569630085253502717648498118383356859371345327180116960300442655802073660515692068448059163472438726337412639721611668963365329274524683795898803515844109273846119396045513151325096835254352967440214290024900894106148249792936857620252669314267990625341054382109413982209048217613474462366099211988610838771890047771108303025697073942786800963584597671865634957073868371020540520001351340594968828107972114104065730887195267530118107925564666923847891177478488560095588773415349153603883278280369727904581288187557648454461776700257309873313090202541988023337650601111667962042284633452143391122583377206859791047448706336804001357517229485133041918063698840034398827807588137953763403631303885997729562636716061913967514574759718572657335136386433456038688663246414030999145140712475929114601257259572549175515657577056590262761777844800736563321827756835035190363747258466304L

Answer (score 3):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish)

**2020 update:**

`'*:*l1=?n!`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X13LSivH0NY@T/H/fwA)

A nice, big number.

6607775919524790651439701166707789489378797865523309469653600804966653717124420234900643695716633983263105744751733811265946551350757473520290996592227365993351117075631863250858664418726460620430636874466736708735091515674858617262672061392356105274688381926671523379031815127376998794734801639561117309008230181917173237247958670364395979998445068443549603086925428413456037483510188036968643022754136876546302694036337733250775972540791054488317803988268522700511802405629821189614545680714572177873101991977461377780062066275613653646526353437038254323542049537486740164431723433218814788820554530926749282165106713414138827765731299184793201063834591836604608194080942136186867241173559749340134123556348756219648917627921044482452298279885527390296021299809895208344965720017693561708427752229404713795765501476321809083160697802384075712539404128882728723305116462257211512254983151160419880169748505483542215949682009001146040637299350914438311533945478015790682139849329365319957805121129755402607972548916020445921204515251014341335241310585757251648664383763145215969276240907124147926204015695626240000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

---

### <s>3147440830160257032480100000000</s> 319626579315078487616775634918212890625

**Edit:**

Seems like I am allowed to exclude the characters needed for printing, the `n` in this case, so here is an updated version:

```
':*:*:*:*nÿ
```

**Original answer:**

```
'*:*:*:*n;
```

Here, `'` activates stringmode, and pushes all the following characters to the stack, before wrapping and exiting stringmode. Then it does a multiply-and-copy chain, printing the number, and exits. Of interest here is the ascii value of `n` 110, and `;` 59.

However, if we allow it to terminate with an error, we can abuse the fact that the official interpreter supports Unicode. The title of the question says bytes, but the text says characters, so the following program is just for the fun of it.

```
'*:*:*:*n
```

Outputting 1867215243681462552708446358738678532523702556144100000000

Alternatively, to stick to bytes, `ÿ` at the end gives us 383233022803952503175039062500000000, and that is still nice.

(New "for fun" program `':*:*:*:*n` prints 7587624076546380447593767884781979512738274729546264306618287972087303430335365121)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, non competing

I'm using this to highlight a little know corner of perl.

Perl can't really compete on this one because it doesn't have builtin bignums (of course you could load a bignum library).

But what everybody knows isn't completely true. One core function actually can handle big numbers.

The `pack` format `w` can actually convert any size natural number between base `10` and base `128`. The base 128 integer is however represented as string bytes. The bitstring `xxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzz` become the bytes:  `1xxxxxxx 1yyyyyyy 0zzzzzzz` (every byte starts with 1 except the last one). And you can convert such a string to base 10 with unpack. So you can write code like:

```
unpack w,~A x 4**4 .A
```

which gives:

```
17440148077784539048602210552864286760481312243331966651657423831944908597692986131110771184688683631223604950868378426010091037391551287028966465246275171764867964902846884403624214574779667949236313638077978794791039372380746518407204456880869394123452212674801443116750853569815557532270825838757922217314748231826241930826238846175896997055564919425918463307658663171965135057749089077388054942032051553760309927468850847772989423963904144861205988704398838295854027686335454023567793114837657233481456867922127891951274737700618284015425
```

You can replace the `4**4` by larger values until you feel it takes too long or uses too much memory.

Unfortunately this is way too long for the limit of this challenge, and you can argue that the base 10 result is converted to a string before it becomes the result so the expression doesn't really produce a number. But internally perl really does the needed arithmetic to convert the input to base 10 which I always considered rather neat.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-36 (not 84, 36), 10 bytes, approx. 9.999985426E99

Older calculators can be programmed to an extent as well ;)
 `69!58.4376`
This is very close to the maximum range a TI calculator can display: `-1E100<x<1E100`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## ARM Thumb, multiword integer, <s>~1.157921e+77</s> ~4.973232e+86

Machine code:

```
2306 1fd9 000a b407 b407
```

Assembly

```c
        .globl main
        .thumb
        .thumb_func
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        // start number generation code
        movs    r3, #6             // 2
        subs    r1, r3, #7         // 4
        movs    r2, r1             // 6
        push    {r1, r2, r3}       // 8
        push    {r1, r2, r3}       // 10
        // end number generation code
        // now printf everything
        adr     r0, .Lprintf_str
        bl      printf
        pop     {r1, r2, r3}
        pop     {r1, r2, r3, r4, pc}
        // print 32 bits at a time
.Lprintf_str:
        .asciz "%#08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x\n"
```

[Try it online! (sorta)](https://travis-ci.com/github/easyaspi314/easyaspi-ppcg/jobs/471966547#L435)

Assembles a 288-bit big endian unsigned integer (with little endian words) with the high 96 bits in `r1-r3` and the low 192 bits on the stack.

The number is, in hex, `0xffffffffffffffff00000006ffffffffffffffff00000006ffffffffffffffff00000006`, or in base 10, `497323236409786642128422301523609912453495901056838330362914156057471888398396751347718`.

## Explanation

You may be wondering why I chose `6` and `7`. The reason is because of the limitations of narrow instructions.

[`movs Rd, #imm` can only encode an 8-bit immediate from `0-255`](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289878994.htm). No negatives allowed, which would make this almost *too* easy.

[`subs Rd, Rn, #imm` can only encode a 3-bit immediate from `0-7`](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289908389.htm). I can only subtract `0-255` if I use the same destination register, which isn't very helpful.

So therefore, since `r1` will be more significant, we put `6` in `r3`, then subtract `7` to get `-1`, or `0xFFFFFFFF`, in `r1`.

```c
        movs    r3, #6             // 2
        subs    r1, r3, #7         // 4
```

Now, time for things to get super dumb.

First, we duplicate `0xFFFFFFFF` to `r2` using `movs`.

```c
        movs    r2, r1             // 6
```

Then, we (ab)use ARM's `push` instruction. ARM's `push` instruction (as well as its sibling `stm`) can push multiple registers at once to the stack, effectively doing a block copy.

We abuse this to copy `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` to the stack twice, tripling the width of the integer.

You could say this is some form of exponentiation, but all I'm doing is pushing to the stack. Nothing suspicious here.

```c
        push    {r1, r2, r3}       // 8
        push    {r1, r2, r3}       // 10
```

Now, it looks like this:

```
   r1: 0xFFFFFFFF    r2: 0xFFFFFFFF
   r3: 0x00000006
 sp+0: 0xFFFFFFFF  sp+4: 0xFFFFFFFF
 sp+8: 0x00000006 sp+12: 0xFFFFFFFF
sp+16: 0xFFFFFFFF sp+20: 0x00000006
```

## ARM Thumb-2, softfloat, 1.797693e+308

Machine code:

```
f248 0310 041b 17da 43db
```

Assembly:

```c
        .thumb
        .globl main
        .thumb_func
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        // Begin number generation code
        movw    r3, #0x8010     // 4
        lsls    r3, r3, #16     // 6
        asrs    r2, r3, #31     // 8
        mvns    r3, r3          // 10
        // End number generation code
        adr     r0, .printf_str
        bl      printf
        pop     {r4, pc}

        .align 4
.printf_str:
        .asciz "%f\n"
```

[Try it online! (sorta)](https://travis-ci.com/github/easyaspi314/easyaspi-ppcg/jobs/471966548#L421)

Creates the 64-bit constant `0x7fefffffffffffff`, which is `DBL_MAX`, in `r2-r3` (since the AAPCS aligns 64-bit integers to even registers)

Specifically, `179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000`

We do this by first putting `~(*(long long*)&DBL_MAX) >> 48` in `r3`, shifting left by 16, doing an arithmetic shift right into `r2` to make it `0xFFFFFFFF`, then do a one's complement to get `r3` to `0x7fefffff`.

## ARM Thumb-2, (non-competing), softfloat + printf merging, 2.148532e+319

Machine code:

```
f248 0110 0409 43ca 0013
```

Assembly:

```c
        .thumb
        .globl main
        .thumb_func
main:
        push    {r4, lr}
        // Begin number generation code
        movw    r1, #0x8010     // 4
        lsls    r1, r1, #16     // 6
        mvns    r2, r1          // 8
        movs    r3, r2          // 10
        // End number generation code
        adr     r0, .printf_str
        bl      printf
        pop     {r4, pc}

        // Combine 0x80100000u (2148532224) with the same double we had before.
.printf_str:
        .asciz "%u%f\n"
```

[Try it online! (sorta)](https://travis-ci.com/github/easyaspi314/easyaspi-ppcg/jobs/471967696#L424)

This is obviously cheating, as it is actually generating an unsigned integer and a double and printing them together, but decided to add it for the lulz.

It basically does this:

```c
uint32_t r1 = (~0x7fef) & 0xffff;
// 0x80100000
r1 <<= 16;
uint32_t r2 = ~r1;
uint32_t r3 = r2;
// 0x7fefffff7fefffff
uint64_t r2r3 = r2 | ((uint64_t)r3 << 32);
double d = *(double*)&r2r3;
printf("%u%f\n", r1, d);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Scala, 2<sup>63</sup>-1

Poor, poor Scala. Takes at least 8 characters to get a `BigInt` value, which doesn't leave enough room to actually make it big.

But with only 7 characters of (counted) code, we can print the largest possible positive `Long`:

```
print(-1L>>>1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Brainf**k  256 - 2147483647

```
>+[<+>+]<.
```

<sub>If you ignore the fact that most compilers & interpreters output data as it's ascii equivalent (be leanient, it is what it is ;) )</sub>, this will return the maximum value of the interpreter/compiler's datatype.

On some systems this is just 256, although on some (mine for example), this is the max value of a 32 bit integer, ie 2 147 483 647.

Edit:

```
-.
```

Will print the same thing in many fewer characters

Comment: That second answer will print `-1` on interpreters that use signed values for the tape

Answer (score 2):

## Braingolf, I don't even know [non-competing]

```
#~U&^^^^^^
```

Doesn't work on TIO as I need to get Dennis to pull, but as you can see [here](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf/blob/master/braingolf.py#L359), `U` in Braingolf calculates a range from 1 to the last item on the stack, in this case `~` or 126

Then reduces the entire stack with exponentiation, meaning the stack now contains 1 value which is equal to `126^125^124...^2^1`

We'll call this value `n` from now on.

Then I had some bytes left, so I filled them with some monadic `^` operators.

This means the final output is `(((((n^n)^n)^n)^n)^n)`

For reference, `126^125` is `3.518180682714907e+262` and `(126^125)^124` is ~35000 digits long

Comment: For all intended purposes, this is approximately a_127 in the [exponential factorial](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Exponential_factorial).

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto)

```
kτ\p******u
```

Prints out

<s>1 * 10<sup>846</sup></s> (2017)

<s>1.1 * 10<sup>846</sup></s> (2018)

<s>1.3 * 10<sup>846</sup></s> (2019)

6.89 * 10<sup>13537</sup> (2019)

#### Explanation

```
k - makes the stack 'sticky' so that values when popped are only copied,
 not removed
τ - pushes the date on the stack (the year is on the top, 2017 right now...)
\ - escapes the next character (print)
p - (ignored on first go-around)
*
 *
  *
   *        Multiplies top element by second, but stack has one element so it does it by itself
    *
     *
      *
       *
u - reverses instruction pointer direction
       *
      *
     *
    *
   *
  *
 *
*
p - prints
\ - escapes the date
k - makes stack sticky
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//z/7fEtMgRYYlP7/DwA)

Comment: actually you can add another `*` since `p` is excluded from bytecount

Answer (score 2):

## [Runic](https://tio.run/#runic)

This answer is only works, if the following things are true:

1. I implement the Ackermann function using a [non stack overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186672/how-can-i-prevent-my-ackerman-function-from-overflowing-the-stack) implementation.

   - Which I did briefly last night, but removed as there is no useful reason to keep it
   - It did successfully calculate [`Ack(4,3)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwunc.png) over the course of 20-30 seconds, a number with `19729` digits.
2. If there are no arbitrary execution limits (e.g. TIO's 60 second timeout)
3. The executing computer has an arbitrary amount of memory to store exceedingly large stacks of BigIntegers

But if given those, then this program...

```
'ÿY:A:A:A@
```

...prints a number so large simply calculating how many *digits* it has is impossible, due to the explosive nature of the Ackermann sequence. Heck the inputs to the first call are both 255000!

The output (and thus input to the next call) is (in Knuth up-arrow notation): 2 ↑<sup>254998255003</sup> - 3
(that's 254 BILLION arrows!)

### Explanation

```
>                Implicit entry
 'ÿ              Pushes the character ÿ onto the stack (which will be implicitly converted to an `int`
                    whenever a math operator is called on it).
   Y             Multiply by 1000 (the 'biggest' thing we can apply to a single stack value in 1 byte) 
    :            Duplicate top item on the stack
     A           Pop x and y, call Ack(x,y)
      :          Duplicate top item on the stack
       A         Pop x and y, call Ack(x,y)
        :        Duplicate top item on the stack
         A       Pop x and y, call Ack(x,y)
          @      Print the entire stack, top to bottom (there's only 1 value) and terminate
```

#### Larger still?

```
`AAAAAAAA@
```

Push the character sequence `A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,@` onto the stack (9 items) as the instruction pointer begins a character sequence on ` and loops around until it sees ` again. Each `A` then invokes `Ack(x,y)` (where `x` is the top of the stack) until the stack contains 1 entry, printing it. Not sure if this is actually larger or not.

### However...

The closest we can get by abiding by the limitations is this:

```
':pba,*@
```

(Note the non-printing character 0x8F in position 2)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/9UL9VQVKijpbD//8A)

Which prints `1.79657789596691E+308` (143<sup>143</sup> * 1.1). The multiplier of 1.1 is the largest that can be applied without rolling over to infinity due to the limits on a double: even multiplying by `a9,` (1.11) is sufficient to trigger the infinity bit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 456,574 digits

```perl6
[*] 1..ↈ
```

No TIO because it takes 2 minutes to run.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), 260144641↑260144641

```
*:*(:|:*
```

Surprised I was able to get it this high, probably can be improved

Edit: Improved by [A__](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85052/a)

## How it works

```
   Pushes 127 to the stack twice, I used 127 since it is the highest number that can be pushed in 1 byte (Note there is two characters there, they're just unprintables)
*    Multiplies them
:*   Squares that
(    Begin a for loop
:|   That will run 260144641 times (since that is the top element of the stack)
:*   That squares the top element of the stack
At the end it will automatically get printed
```

Comment: No, ```z``` isn't the largest number possible with 1 byte; 0x7F [is](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/vl7LSkvDqsZK6/9/AA). I usually use unprintable characters when I golf in Keg, to represent specific constants.

Comment: Oh wow, I was struggling to paste that into TIO, thanks for the better solution :)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm pretty sure [this](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/vl5Lw0rDqsZK6/9/AA) is way higher, but I have no clue how to calculate what that would be

Comment: Wait nvm, I forgot the | on the first bracket

Comment: If you were using that, you would need to close out the brackets at the end in order to output it, so I don't think it could be higher

Comment: I am requesting an exponentation operator in Unofficial Keg.

Comment: The PR has been merged. Now you can use the ```Ẹ``` operator to represent larger numbers. (at the cost of using more bytes)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), ~\$4.24 \times 10^{1177545600} \$

```
'****l(?;n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X10LCHI07K3z/v8HAA)

Outputs the ordinal value of `*` (42) around 4088700 times. Every loop it only terminates if the length of the stack is higher than multiplying the ordinal values of `l(?;n` = 108*40*63*59*110 = 1766318400, but since it only pushes 3 elements to the stack each time, this takes a *long* while.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 1.84467422290351e+26 (On a 64-bit machine)

```
perl -le "print ~0*9999999"
```

Comment: Your code was the inspiration for [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31790/2771).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7 - <strike>8794643931199480236</strike> 15616093818140822

```
print hash('zz')
```

Comment: Um, that's 12 chars.

Comment: Ehh valid point @user80551. Guess I was slightly distracted by the footy match on TV :-)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, more than 13 003 624 633 896 (but it reads a clock)

```
9*new Date
```

Reading from a clock is effectively taking an input. Feels like cheating. However, the technique seems to be well-received in the answers here.

#### If clocks are not allowed, then:

### JavaScript, 186 025 771 008

```
99*(7<<28)
```

Trigonometry takes too many bytes (`Math.sin`, `Math.PI`).

Bit-shift goes near the integer maximum, then multiplication yields a floating point.

Comment: Bit shift operation are limited to 32 bit integers. 60 == 28 used in a shift operation (try in console: [7<<28, 7<<60])

Answer (score 1):

### C++ prints 18446744073709551615

## #

ULLONG_MAX is 10 characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<ULLONG_MAX<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what value does that print?

Comment: @KyleKanos Fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

### [TXR:](http://nongnu.org/txr)

```
$ txr -p '(mask 999)'
535754303593133660474212524530000905280702405852766803721875194185175525562468061246
599189407847929063797336458776573412593572642846157810728751889829846429852761096554
990320661140395677219337642394922319490470301292036210344653556258987007434741839952
7286296858625998634149561158533358569939198279680
```

Comment: What is this doing?

Comment: @g.rocket It makes a bit mask in which bit 999 is set. It takes multiple arguments, e.g `(mask 1 2)` yields 6.

Answer (score 1):

**Bash / shell**

> You may exclude from the 10-character limit any code necessary to
>   print anything.
>
> ... you can use up to 16 characters for your program.

**(6 chars for code + 7 chars for printing = 26 digits) = 6888888 digits**

```
$ seq -s9 999999
```

---

This number is bigger, but people may argue that it's in the wrong format.

> The output may be in any format (so you can print 999, 5e+100, etc.).

**(8 chars for code + 8 chars for printing = 26 digits) = more than 1183888008 digits**

```
$ seq -s9 99999999
```

It usually takes around a minute to print the number and it contains the scientific representation of it.

---

Some funny example:

**(10 chars = 26 digits)**

```
echo $$$$$$$$$$
2760127601276012760127601
```

See: [What does $$ mean in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell)

Comment: Your program must calculate a single number and print it. You can not print a string, nor can you print the same digit thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

Perl: 6.27710173538668e+57 on cygwin with a Perl 32 bit

```
perl -e 'print ~0*~0*~0, "\n"'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ozone, 9e+90000

```
(1)n1n1s2
```

Though it depends on dialect.

Answer (score 1):

### Befunge-93, ~2.49e+40

```
"**:*:*:*.
```

This works by pushing the ASCII values of the program onto the stack and doing a bunch of multiplication.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in TIO, but it does in [this](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html) interpreter.

Here is a worse version that actually works in [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@6@koqKlZQWEev//AwA):

```
"$$**:*:*.
```

And prints `1152921504606846976`.
TIO ended up pushing a lot of spaces and 2 zeroes at the end, so I had to get rid of those.

Note that both of these programs print the number forever, because the end command (`@`) would have taken up a precious byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Brain-Flak, 100 (non-competing)

```
(()@lt99)
```

Note that this code must be run with the `-d` flag which adds 3 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#0/ivoemQU2Jp@V/z/3/dFAA)

This uses the `@lt` debug flag in the ruby interpreter. This flag simply adds the following number to the value which is then pushed by the enclosing parentheses.

The enclosing parentheses do not modify the number and are required for it to be printed so they are not counted towards then 10 bytes.

The `()` adds one to the value and causes the interpreter to recognize the enclosing parentheses as pushing a value (parentheses will only push a value if they enclose non-debug flag Brain-Flak code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), number in the Demo Output because it is very extense (has 30104 digits)

```
namespace path tcl::mathop
puts [<< 9 99999]
```

The relevant part is

```
<< 9 99999
```

, the rest is boilerplate.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f8/LzE3tbggMTlVoSCxJEOhJDnHyioXyMov4CooLSlWiLaxUbBUsASB2P//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 999999

```
19*3
Write _
Write _
Write _
Write _
Write _
Write _
```

As any  code necessary to output anything is excluded,  all 'Write ' statements are excluded.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9/QUsuYK7wosyRVIZ5Y@v9/AA)

Comment: > Your program must calculate a single number and print it. You can not print a string, nor can you print the same digit thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 9 bytes, MAX INT (9223372036854775807)

```
echo ~0^1<<63;
```

or

```
echo -1^1<<63;
```

Set an int of all bits on (-1) then XOR it with an int of only the first bit on to flip the sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), (only 6 bytes)

```
9!ḞɳƖ*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fUvHhjnknNx@bpvX/PwA)

[Link to number](https://pastebin.com/jmR6kaDA)

I don't really see any point in getting any bigger than this. Anything else exceeds the runtime limit on TIO

```
9  pushes 9
!  factorial of 9 (362880)
Ḟ  push xth Fibonacci Number (really big)
ɳ  push 0123456789
₫  reverse ("987654321")
Ɩ  cast to int ("987654321")
*  multiplies
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 730 quadrillion digits

```
9+<now*now
```

This builds the Perl 5 solution (`time*time`) and the Javascript (bit shifting).  Time is currently around 1.56 billion, so we square it (~2.44 quintillion), and then bitshift 9 (because > 1 ha) a fairly insane number of digits to the right.  Perl 6 uses arbitrary precision integers, and that applies to bitshifting as well.  Bit shifting in and of itself doesn't take hardly any time at all, it's just a question of memory restraint and the largest super computers ought to have sufficient, but I don't on my puny laptop.

Given 2<sup>10x</sup> ≈ 10<sup>3x</sup>, we can surmise that there should be around some 730 quadrillion digits if I did my math right.  Times out on TIO for `9+<$x` where $x > 1000000, but handles 100000 in sub 1 secs ao no TIO link.  Answer of course will continue to grow exponentially

(if that's considered out of bounds, though, can just make it `9+<now` which should still fetch a fairly high number, or any other technique to generate the largest in-bounds number at in 7 digits)

Comment: Wouldn't a bitshift of 1 quadrillion (base 2) be 300 *trillion* digits (base 10)?

Comment: @Draco18s erm yes. Should be 730 quadrillion off of 2.4 *quintillion* digits (a billion squared nets a quintillion not a quadrillion)

Comment: I knew one of the two was wrong. I just didn't validate the billion-squared. ;)

Comment: @Draco18s I blame my lack of coffee at the time lol.  In any case, result = "really big", certainly bigger than anything not using a built-in `ack()` function

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg#Command_Glossary), 1.85302E+15

It is definitely the worst answer here...

```
9:*:*:*:*.
```

Comment: Got it up to [221533456↑221533456](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189663/87923) by using a for loop with the fact that alpha-numeric characters get auto-pushed to the stack

Answer (score 1):

### BBC BASIC 2

7 bytes

```
P.2^127
```

Result

```
1.70141181E38
```

[image: BBC BASIC]

As commented the previous answer may violate the exponation rule, so here's something using the EXP (exponent) function instead.

```
P.EXP(88)
```

which returns

```
1.65163622E38
```

[image: BBC BASIC 2]

Comment: Is this using scientific notation?

Comment: It is 2 raised to the power of 127, so if that is consider "exponentiation" I'll retract. The example above was 9e+99.

Comment: Okay my misunderstanding then.

Answer (score 1):

## Deadfish~, ~~2↑4000

`{{{iss}}}o`

Crashes TIO, but in theory works.

This means:

Repeat 1000 times: add one, than square twice.

First iteration: 0 => 1 => 1 => 1
Second iteration: 1 => 2 => 4 => 16
Third iteration: 16 => 17 => 289 => 83521
And after this it grows without bound.

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.3](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.3), 9222471316929301708

```
func main:
push 1.9
bits
asl
print
ret
end
```

#### Explanation

The minimum code needed to print something in CSASM is as follows:

```
func main:
push <something>
print
ret
end
```

Thus, I took the liberty of having the 10-byte limit be on the `<something>` rather than the entire program, as is mentioned in the challenge:

> You may exclude from the 10-character limit any code necessary to print anything.

Otherwise, this language wouldn't be able to even have a submission for this challenge.
(The boilerplate for an empty `main` function is **16** bytes.)

So, that leaves me with figuring out how to best use those 10 bytes.  Hence, I abused one of the instructions in the language:  **`bits`**

According to the [`syntax.txt`](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/blob/38ce499bcb04f72fe014de500d149698583efc95/syntax.txt#L90) file:

> Pops A (an `<f32>` or `<f64>`), then pushes an `<i32>` or `<i64>` set to the bit representation of A

... where **A** stands for "the top value on the stack".

In short, a single- or double-precision floating-point value is popped from the stack.  The value's bit representation (sign, exponent, mantissa) is then stored into a 32- or 64-bit integer value and that integer value is pushed to the stack.

#### Why use 1.9?

The bit representation of `1.9` is:
$$
00111111 11111110 01100110 01100110 01100110 01100110 01100110 01100110
$$
This value interpreted as an `i64` (or `long`) would be `4611235658464650854`.  However, this can be better.
Using the last 3 available bytes, we can perform an **A**rithmetic **S**hift **L**eft (`asl`) instruction, to get the following bit representation instead:
$$
01111111 11111100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100
$$
... which ends up being `9222471316929301708` instead.

If I were to use any value larger than `1.9` within the limits of the 3 bytes for the number (say, `2.0`), the **exponent** part of the bit representation would be `10000000000` or some larger number.

The MSB in the exponent would get shifted left into the **sign** bit, resulting in a negative end result.  Not good.

Furthermore, if I were to not use the `asl` instruction and instead opted to use `1.9999`, the value would still be smaller than using `1.9` and the `asl` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (TI-83), 9.999999314e99

```
68!4032.2
```

very close to the soft limit of the calculator (`-1e100<x<1e100`). It can be overcome and get closer to the hard limit (`1e128`) but not in less than 10 characters.

`69!58.4376` is a good contender too but not as close

## TI-Basic (TI-89), 9.99999681785e999

```
449!259.61
```

Again, quite close to the limit (`1e1000` gets automatically replaced with `∞`)

Answer (score 1):

## [KonamiCode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/KonamiCode), 1,000,000

`v(^>>>>>>)<<<` (Note: This excludes `<<<` because it is used for output.)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam - 40.4 million digits

```
1X27m<m<
```

Assuming bit shift is ok, this calculates 1<<(1<<27). It takes about 15 minutes on my laptop, using java 8 to run the [interpreter](http://sf.net/p/cjam).

Comment: Hey, aditsu, did you design CJam?

Comment: @404NotFound yeah, but a lot of it is like GolfScript

Comment: Cool, where did you learn parsing to write an interpreter? I'm really interested in parsing etc., but I'm only 12 (no CS courses ;() I'm currently reading "Parsing Techniques: a Practical Guide" and *trying* to write my toy compiler in C++

Comment: @404NotFound I'm not sure I can answer exactly... my first experience with parsing was probably writing an arithmetic expression evaluator, and I learned that from a book or maybe somebody else's source code. In university I learned something about formal languages - finite automata, formal grammars (of different types) and parsing techniques. Then I read a few things on the net about some other types of parsers, and wrote some code to try things out, but I can't say I learned a lot, and I'm not really good at this. I designed CJam to be easy to parse, something like C++ is MUCH MUCH harder.

Comment: *Of course* I'm not trying to parse C++, I mean I write simple parsers *in* C++... In retrospect, was the university's class really crucial? Or did it have a more mild effect on your learning?

Comment: @404NotFound I'm not sure how crucial, but an understanding of the basic formal language theory is definitely important.

Answer (score 0):

### `units` interactive shell, 3.085369e+68

You read that right, I know it's not much but it's definitely different.

```
9999Ypc
ym
```

I'm assuming newline counts as a character and the invocation of `units` counts as code essential to print.
`Ypc` is yotta parsec, `ym` is yocto meter.

```
You have: 9999Ypc
You want: ym
    * 3.085369e+68
    / 3.2411034e-69
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#: 1.8E+19

Unfortunately we can't bit-shift doubles.

```
using System;
namespace BigNum10Bytes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Playing with ulongs 
            Console.WriteLine(ulong.MaxValue);
            Console.WriteLine(~(1UL<<64)); // 10 chars, 18446744073709551614
            Console.WriteLine(8191UL<<51); // 10 chars, 18444492273895866368

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cjam - alot

alot:

```
99999999m!
```

even more:

```
9999999,m!
```

Unfortunately i cant calculate the result. But refering to wikipedia `14842907m!` 
would be 2.788662975×10 ^ 100 000 000

Comment: `99999,m!si` should be much larger.

Comment: @jimmy23013 but why the `si`?

Comment: To remove the leading zero... or just use two more 9s if that is allowed.

Comment: @jimmy23013 ty for the hint, i think `9999999,m!` could have won this challange (:

Comment: If my calculation is correct it's only about `10^(8.28*10^65657059)`. Those numbers from Ackermann functions are much much larger.

Comment: Note that `m!` was added in version 0.6.5, this question is much older. Also see Dennis's CJam answer.

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>8,589,934,592</s> 274,877,906,944

```
?#RED*#RED
```

`#RED` is a constant for the color red (`&HFFF80000`)

The expression only takes up 9 characters, so I can print it in 10 characters without decreasing the number.

Comment: You're not allowed to use exponential functions, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I didn't see that. fixed.

Comment: Printing doesn't count in the count, so you'd be able to print it anyway.

Comment: I know, but I had 1 byte left over that I couldn't use for anything else

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram

```
999999999!
```

Result:

```
9.90462657922299373728082110506570432171722139002... × 10^8565705513
```

Eight and a half billion digits!

This is the biggest I could find without using a named function such as "ack()".

Comment: Why not `9!!!!!!!!!`?  Based on the accepted answer, I don't think anyone cares about run-time and physical constraints anymore.

Comment: Wolfram didn't like it when I put two factorial symbols consecutively, it seemed to be applying a different operation.  Try it with 3!! and wolfram returns 3 as the answer instead of 720.  A bug in wolfram?  Do I win a prize ? :)

Comment: Apparently "double factorial" is a thing - but it doesn't do what I'd have expected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: See [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31747/58880) on how to do the factorials.

Comment: What about `((999!)!)!`? I don't know Wolfram, but I expect brackets are supported

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 10 bytes ~ 2 × 10<sup>273964</sup>

```
17932!:*:*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/39Dc0thI0UrLSut/UWpBkYKVQnFmVapCSmZxgUJ@acl/AA) Snippet outputs the length, then the number itself.

This calculates (17932!)<sup>4</sup> (without exponentiation) using scientific precision, so only a constant width is perpetuated. The number looks like:

```
204449781735459736090000000000000000...00000000000000000
```

This [Wolfram|Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(17932!)%5E4) shows what the precise calculation would look like.

Comment: it's currently broken :(

Answer (score 0):

## x86_64 machine language (Linux) ~2.808896e+307

```
0:       f2 0f 10 05 fa ff ff    movsd  -0x6(%rip),%xmm0        # 2
7:       ff 
8:       c3                      retq   
9:       7f
```

This moves the IEEE-754 double precision float `7f c3 ff ff ff fa 05 10` to `%xmm0` and returns.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBCsIwEADveUWJCBuxUhXxoPiSvcRNtgZjWpoUguLXjfHkYRgGhtqeqJSFC@RnY88xGTdsbhfx0C6AeommGScXEoNcWgxyDWCG@eotrBQoJTHzDnPHmLdd9aG2rvAf2mM@svzdJ/Eu5UPsdR9L@7TZUkya7l8)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 4E+30103

```
9n<<99999n
```

Uses big integers so actually goes way past what normal integers could reach.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 9 * 10^4202512

`printf("9%.*u","");` or `printf("9%0*u","");`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dhx5WZV6KQm5iZp6FZzVVQBOSlaSippsTkKekoKWlaK@jrK5gYGRiZGhr9h8laqupplUKk/9f@BwA)

The shortest way to print anything in C (afaik) is `puts("");` which is 9 bytes
19 - 9 = 10

`.*` specifies precision which isn't exponentiation

> .number
>
> For integer specifiers (d, i, o, u, x, X) − precision specifies the
>   minimum number of digits to be written. If the value to be written is
>   shorter than this number, the result is padded with leading zeros. The
>   value is not truncated even if the result is longer. A precision of 0
>   means that no character is written for the value 0. For e, E and f
>   specifiers − this is the number of digits to be printed after the
>   decimal point. For g and G specifiers − This is the maximum number of
>   significant digits to be printed. For s − this is the maximum number
>   of characters to be printed. By default all characters are printed
>   until the ending null character is encountered. For c type − it has no
>   effect. When no precision is specified, the default is 1. If the
>   period is specified without an explicit value for precision, 0 is
>   assumed.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf

So you'll get 9 followed by `""` digits,(4202512)
the very last ones read from memory as the number to print is not specified,
adding `,0` would prevent memory reading but push it over the 10 byte limit

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 7,762,279,691,451,941,920

```
999999axxao
```

I'm trying to get the language on TIO

About 7.76227969 x 10<sup>18</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/),  <s>9 bytes</s>, 7 bytes

```forth
-1. ud.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//6xrqKZSm6P3/DwA)

Produces:
**340282366920938463463374607431768211455**

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), \$\approx 1.609 \times 10^{1859933}\$

```
9!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/99SUfH///8A)

With MathGolf being a language written in Python, the main issue will be calculating the number in a timely fashion. This program produces its output in about a minute. It might be possible to to \$(10!)!\$, which would be significantly bigger. However, the approach and the byte-count is still the same.

Comment: This isn't valid I'm afraid. `#` isn't allowed because of the rule "_You may use any features of your language, **except built-in exponentiation functions**._" But even if you'd change it to `*`, I doubt it would be valid due to the rule "_If it takes longer than an hour to run on the fastest computer in the world, it's invalid._" Creating an array of `timestamp!!!!` amount of items in under an hour would be quite a feat.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh, I should definitely have read the question more thouroughly... I'll think of another approach, and update the answer when I have one.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen fixed and verified.

Answer (score 0):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1+), score 256

```
11+"*"*"*:
```

Begin with 2, square three times, and we get 256. I believe this is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (x86/x86_64), 1.18973e+4932

Improvement on an answer from an inactive user.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>
int main()
{
    std::cout << LDBL_MAX+0 << std::endl;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv6vnJmXnFOakqpgk5lfXFKUmphrx4UQS07LyU8ssePKzCtRyE3MzNPQ5KrmUgCC4pIUK6vk/NISBRub/z4uTj7xvo4R2gb/QXI2NhDp1LyUHGuu2v8A)

[Equivalent C version using `printf` which shows all digits](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44LIZSWk59YAhLKzCtRyE3MzNPQVKjmUgCCgiKgUJqGkqpPmpKOgo@Lk0@8r2OEtoGmNVft//8A).

Depends on the implementation, but x86 chips on Linux use an 80 bit extended double for `long double`. This results in `LDBL_MAX` being 1.18973e+4932, much larger than `ULLONG_MAX`.

Comment: Just so you know, the `+0` isn't required as you don't need to use all 10 bytes. You don't gain anything from removing it either, though. I'm just saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), \$\Large>1.0111110111×10^{146,337}\$

```
žmbbbbbbbb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7cJCj4/x8A) This is the only competing one, the alternative breaks rule 5.

```
žmbbbbbbbb  # full program
         b  # convert...
žm          # 9876543210...
  b         # in binary...
   b        # in binary...
    b       # in binary...
     b      # in binary...
      b     # in binary...
       b    # in binary...
        b   # in binary...
         b  # to binary
            # implicit output
```

## Alternative

This program scores:
$$\large(r_{((x+1)^7-1)}=…(r_2=(r_1=x^x)^{r_1})^{r_2}…)^{r_{((x+1)^7-1)}}\\\Huge x=9{,}876{,}543{,}210$$Note: here, \$\large r_2\$  means the second result. So \$\large r_{((x+1)^7-1)}\$ means the \${\large{((x+1)^7-1)}}^\text{th}\$ result.

```
žmEEEEEEEm
```

---

```
žmEEEEEEEm  # full program
  E         # for N in [0, 1, ...,
žm          # ..., 9876543210...
  E         # ]...
   E        # for N in [0, 1, ...,
žm          # ..., 9876543210...
   E        # ]...
    E       # for N in [0, 1, ...,
žm          # ..., 9876543210...
    E       # ]...
     E      # for N in [0, 1, ...,
žm          # ..., 9876543210...
     E      # ]...
      E     # for N in [0, 1, ...,
žm          # ..., 9876543210...
      E     # ]...
       E    # for N in [0, 1, ...,
žm          # ..., 9876543210...
       E    # ]...
        E   # for N in [0, 1, ...,
žm          # ..., 9876543210...
        E   # ]...
         m  # push...
žm          # 9876543210...
            # (implicit) or top of stack if not first iteration...
         m  # to the power of...
žm          # 9876543210...
            # (implicit) or top of stack if not first iteration
            # implicit output
```

Comment: I've removed most of the `\large` elements in the \$\LaTeX\$ as they're unnecessarily obtrusive